# Error: Could not Find or load main class 0 - TestNG Error

Tags: java, testng

When I run my class as a TestNG Im getting below error,

Error:

> Could not find or load main class 0.

But when i run the class with normal java main method it is working fine.

Can someone please help me.

Comment: Can you provide sample code that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Im not able to write hello world also in @Test method.

Comment: Please post in code.  Are you doing run as ->TestNG test?

Answer (score 0):

After installing the m2e plugin from eclipse it worked.